# Is there a keyboard shortcut in OSX to skip back through the fragments of a word?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut in OSX to 'skip' or tab back through the fragments of a word?

e.g.: 'post_text'

if your cursor is after the final 't', can you skip back to the _ and then back to the p?

(Maybe I'm just missing vi..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mostly depends on the app, but Xcode and Sublime Text 2 support the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Arrow keys to go between subwords.

Comment: To skip to beginning and end of line - use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + Arrow keys.